# Customize Ruby on rails validation errors

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Hi I'm trying to customize some rails form errors. All of which work fine except for the middle one regarding lead_reason_id etc i;m guessing this is because there are no custom validators?

```
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: Validators::Base::EMAIL, message: 'Este campo tiene que ser positivo' }
  validates :lead_reason_id, :lead_source_id, presence: true, format: { message: 'Este campo tiene que ser positivo' }
  validates :amount, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0,  message: 'Este campo tiene que ser positivo' }
```

The error I'm getting is

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if validating several fields with a single `validates` call is allowed. Also, for your `format` hash you need to specify `:with` option, which is missing. If you just want to validate presence, then `format` hash is not necessary:

```
validates :lead_reason_id, presence: { message: 'Este campo tiene que ser positivo' }
validates :lead_source_id, presence: { message: 'Este campo tiene que ser positivo' }
```

See more at: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#format

Comment: Yeah it does actually, however there is another issue. I don't want the 'Lead' on the website? In other words it appears these messages take the model name by default

Comment: Cool thank you, that works but it still outputs the model name before my spanish text ? `Lead reason Este campo tiene que ser positivo
Lead source Este campo tiene que ser positivo`

Comment: In this case you will need a custom validator, which will add error message to ```errors[:base]``` array. See working example in docs again: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#errors-base

Comment: Other option: to use ```errors.messages``` instead of ```errors.full_messages``` in views: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#working-with-validation-errors